# How should i pass a value from Office js function to angular syntax function

Tags: angular, rest, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have built an Office Web Addin in Angular 5 and now I am working with Office Rest Api, I followed the in documentation from [use rest Api in Addins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api)

From the documentation it is cleared that we can call the rest api url with token which we get from the function which is written inside Angular's **ngOnInit()** in myComponent.ts

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true}, function(result){
if (result.status === "succeeded") {
var accessToken = result.value;

// Use the access token
   getCurrentItem(accessToken);
  } else {
// Handle the error
  }
});
```

From above code I am getting the accessToken successfully I have printed it in the console.Now but the issue is I am using Angular 5, So the syntax is conflicting between both because if I create a function named

`getCurrentItem(accessToken)` in Angular 5 Class I must have to call it like `this.getCurrentItem(accessToken)` inside the above which throws the error that

```
'this' is not defined
```

In this case I have tried setting the accessToken in localStorage and get it from the function checkAccessToken like

```
 Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true}, function(result){
  if (result.status === "succeeded") {
    accessToken = result.value;
    localStorage.setItem('apiAccessToken',accessToken)
   // console.log(result.status)
   //this.getCurrentItem(accessToken)
   
  } else {
    console.log(result.status);
  }
});

 getAccessToken(){
   apiAccessToken:any = localStorage.getItem('apiAccessToken');
   console.log("API_Access_token : "+apiAccessToken);
 }
```

So now inside the console I recieve INCOMPLETE Access_token because of I am getting access denied on any rest call I called at the first time, Next time I call the same rest url again with token it works because this time gets the full Access Api Token.

I can Understand that this is happening because before waiting for office **getCallBackTokenAsync()** function to complete, the function **getAccessToken()** gets Called.

Even I cannot call **getAccessToken()** inside the office function because it needs **this.getAccessToken()** which is not acceptable by office function which returns AccessToken, So is there any other way to acheive it or to wait for the **getCallBackTokenAsync()** office function to complete its call

Answer (score 1):

`getCallbackTokenAsync` takes in an optional parameter named `options` which supports the `asyncContext` property. You can pass in an instance of your object that has the `getCurrentItem` method. In your callback function, this object will be available in the result parameter. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5&view=office-js#getCallbackTokenAsync).

Here's sample code to help you:

```
let foo = new Foo();

Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync
(
    {
        "isRest" : false,
        "asyncContext" : foo
    },

    function (result)
    {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)
        {
            let accessToken = result.value;
            localStorage.setItem('apiAccessToken',accessToken);
            console.log(result.status);
            result.asyncContext.getCurrentItem(accessToken);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(result.status);
        }
    }
);
```